# Getting "calling" list size in list closure

Tags: groovy

I need to get the "calling" list size in a Groovy list closure, e.g.:

```
def foo = [1,2,3,4,5]
def bar = foo.findAll {
   someCondition(it)
}.collect {
   processElement(it, <self>.size())
}
```

where `<self>` is the list resulting from filtering `foo` with `findAll`.

Of course, one can save the intermediate result and get its size, but is it possible to do without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can currently think of is:

```
def bar = foo.findAll { someCondition(it) }
             .with { list ->
                 list.collect { processElement(it, list.size()) }
             }
```

But this just uses `with` instead of an intermediate result.

Or, you could use the delegate of a Closure:

```
def foo = [1,2,3,4,5]
def collector = { it -> processElement(it, delegate.size()) }

(collector.delegate = foo.findAll { someCondition(it) }).collect collector
```

But this is just using the delegate as an intermediate result ;-)

Comment: OK, with ```with``` I can do something like ```def result = list.collect``` and then  return ```result``` from the closure without breaking the "pipeline", which is what I am trying to achieve. I'll wait with accepting in case there is a better answer. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the `result` variable, in the example above, `bar` will have the result of the `collect`